# Using the anonymous function in String.replace() method

Tags: javascript, regex, lambda

I have an array of regular expressions, at the moment just one element in length, and a string which I want to search/replace by looping through the array:

```
var str = "i am*happy all the*time",
    rex = [
        /(\S)\s*\*\s*(\S)/g
        ],
    i = 0,
    r = rex.length;
```

This is how I'm trying to achieve this at the moment:

```
for (i; i < r; i += 1) {
    str.replace(rex[i], function(star, p1, p2) {
        console.log(i, star, p1, p2);
        return p1 + '\\s*(.*)\\s*' + p2;
    });
}
```

The result should be `i am*\\s*(.*)\\s*happy all the\\s*(.*)\\s*time`. But at the moment, `str` seems unaffected, even though when I check the console the relevant matches are being made. You can see this for yourself [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3czg/5/).

So am I missing something simple, have I misunderstood something about using lambda expressions in String.replace(), or is there something more fundamentally wrong here?

...

***EXTRA INFO:***
I'm using Chrome 24 right now, in case that's of interest; I had read a while ago that anonymous functions in String.replace() weren't available to all browsers though I assumed that would be resolved by now (the option was introduced in ECMAScript v3).

Comment: JS strings are immutable, and the function *returns* a new string.

Comment: Btw, instead of that function you could just use `"$1\\s*(.*)\\s*$2"`

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. Was aware of the string alternative but am toying around with more complicated functions. Just wanted to get the basics right first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.replace()` doesn't change the original string, but returns the new one. You should assign the result

```
for (i; i < r; i += 1) {
    str = str.replace(rex[i], function(star, p1, p2) {...})
}
```

Comment: So simple. I think the reference book I have throw me off as in none of the examples is a result assigned to a variable. Thanks.